# for loop is not going infinate in python

Tags: python

Why this for loop is not infinite, Here looping on a list and redefine the list inside the loop

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
for i in a:
    print i
    a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
output : 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
```

Comment: The loop continues regardless if you reassign it during iteration. It doesn't go back to the beginning...

Comment: Why would you expect changing the variable `a` after it has already initiated the loop to have any effect on the loop?

Comment: @AndrewLi yes you are right, that is the behavior it is showing, But I am excepting a detailed explanation about this.

Comment: @AChampion Why can't experiment in such a way when python is allowing me to do ?

Comment: You can, I'm asking why you think it would affect the already bound loop? E.g. `b = a; a = [1, 2, 3]` the latter assignment has not effect on `b`.

Comment: @Arun:  please see fulsome explanation below.  achampion and I are trying to explain to you that the iteration of the for loop is bound just prior to the execution of the body of the for loop **unless you modify the array being looped over as shown in the examples below**.  Finally, just because you can do it, doesn’t mean that you should.

Comment: After looping on a variable I am changing the state of the veritable, So I was excepting  an error or it should go an inconsistent state. @AChampion

Comment: @Arun you are not changing the state of the object that the for loop is bound to, you are assigning a new object to `a`. `a` is just a label to an object. The same reason `a = 1; b = a; a = 5` doesn't change `b` to 5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Roughly speaking, the loop is not infinite because the iterator that `i` is bound to is bound when the code execution reaches the `for . . . in` loop.  After that, all successive calls are to `iter.next()` which will move the existing iterator to the next position regardless of any subsequent redefinition of `a`.

Recall that arrays have a built in function called `__iter__` (or `iter`).  Then, your `for` loop is equivalent to :

```
a = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
it = iter(a)
try:
    while True:
        print next(it) # for compatibility you may want to use next(it)
        a = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ]
except StopIteration:
    pass
```

Note that in the equivalent code above, any changes to `a` don't affect `i` since `i` is already bound to an iterator looping over the first `[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ]`.

You can observe this by changing the first value of `a`:

```
a = [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
for i in a:
    print i
    a = [ 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 ]
```

note that `a = [ 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 ]` doesn't change the existence of the `[ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]` from the first line since that array already exists in memory.  The subsequent calls each allocate a new array and assign it to `a`.

Comment: I think this answer does the best at explaining what is going on, but there are a few things I think are more confusing than they need to be. For one, I'd not mix up the `i` value from the for loop with the iterator that's generating it. Use a different name like `it` for the iterator. I'd also produce the iterator with the `iter` builtin, rather than calling the `__iter__` method directly on the list. I'd also suggest using `next(it)` rather than `it.next()`. The builtin `next` function is much better for forwards compatibility, since Python 3 would require `it.__next__()`.

Comment: This can also be verified by printing `id(a)` before the `for` loop and `id(a)` after the `for` loop. Both the memory address will be different. Also in each iteration `a`'s address inside the for loop may differ.

Answer (score 1):

Since `a` is not being modified (you are just setting it to the same value), the `for` loop proceeds as expected. What you are expecting is for the `for` loop to restart when `a` is reassigned, but this does not happen.

Instead, to make it infinite, try:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
for i in a:
    print i
    a.append(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, why you need this, but this might help you

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
for i in a:
    print i
    a.append(10) #or anything else-))
```

[use this tool](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) to see what happens in your code.

Comment: Bad idea to change the object you are iterating over: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#for

Comment: I preferer `a.append(i)`, it brings some pattern to infinity :)

Comment: @AChampion, i know it is bad. actually it is extremely meaningless not even to be bad -))

Comment: @TomR sure, but nothing seems rational when you are dealing with absurdity -)) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absurdity

Answer (score 0):

You can even modify not only the content of the list but event the value of the variable and you will have the same result.

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
for i in a:
    print i
    a = "Hello World!"
```

In the `for` the values are loaded so any modification inside the loop will not be taken into consideration.